# Java - HTTP Post, Website login with cookies, java equivalent to this PHP cURL Code?

Tags: java, php, http, post, curl

I am working on creating an application that is capable of logging into myspace accounts in order to automate things on myspace and inside of applications hosted on myspace.

I use this code in my php scripts to login to a myspace account

```
curl_setopt($ch = curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.myspace.com/auth/login");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "formLocation=popupForm&hash=MIGcBgkrBgEEAYI3WAOggY4wgYsGCisGAQQBgjdYAwGgfTB7AgMCAAECAmYDAgIAwAQIzvUlf32XiZkEEEdO4p%252f8EKHJN%252fdOXnKVVcIEUKWnrWfUbv6Jk9HLwI9PjqtfMX%252fCWQApDLaJsH2ntEdJIcsEonDrhad4JCpLBfbLcDb7uo7p1XYlqJNIHme%252fw8m6%252fYfsjQr3k36C4Z8U1IEY&SMSVerifiedCookieToken=&NextPage=&js=-1&fbtoken=&Email=".urlencode($Email)."&Password=".urlencode($Password)."&Remember=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.myspace.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$Result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What would be the equivalent to this but in java?

Comment: Not quite sure why the code did not show up in code format, It is hard to read.. I apologize

Answer (score 1):

May be the [java.net.HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)